Fetch records based on logged in user's country
I have a report on a custom object A__c.
There is a custom field there named User_Country__c, which contains country value of the record.
The report is showing reocrds of all countries.
But I need to show only for the current user's country. The user also have a custom field named Country__c.
I want to show only records which have same value in User_Country__c as current user's country.
I tried adding relative filter. But it only takes $USER as option:

This does not solve the issue.
I tried manually adding $USER.Country__c in filter:

After this no records are being displayed.
How can I show A__c's record with current user's Country__c in the reocrd's User_Country__c?

To solve this I have created a boolean formula field in object A__c: Is_Current_User_Country__c(Using TEXT in formula as Country__c in User is picklist):

Added filter in the report:

It is showing only current logged in users records.
